# I’m having problems with coworker, should I quit?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

Okay, I’m just trying to get through college, and I work full time at a gas station during overnights. I get along with all my coworkers except the new girl. She is just absolutely out there. She is constantly talking about weed as if it’s a fix for everything. She hands out her number even though she’s married. And worse of all, she doesn’t take criticism well.

Problem is, she is constantly talking about how terrible her life has been with a meth addicted father. I have a sister who’s struggling with drugs herself. I shared that with her after I tried to connect on that to try to ease the tension. She then found my sister and told her I’ve been talking about her to literally everyone about her addiction (which is not true) So not only has she possibly ruined what little relationship I had with my sister, she’s been trying to get me fired since she started. I don’t do anything to be fired about.

My boss is setting up a meeting, and I just want to transfer stores because it’s getting to be too much with school and now drama in the work place. I only have a few months left in this place until I can find a job as a pharmaceutical technician in training, but I can’t handle it. Should I just quit (two weeks notice for sure) or should I just transfer? 
Edit: To how she’s been trying to get me fired; she’s been trying to spread horrible lies about me to my coworkers and even to my boss about how I was trying to “fight” a customer. Yeah, I don’t fight, I’m a coward. And then she also makes comments to my boss that I’m lazy and she has to do all the work (clearly not true), and my other coworkers are getting frustrated with her too

Comment: If the girl is new and she's the one acting unprofessionally then there is no reason for you to move. As you have been there for a longer time than her and act professionally, your boss should be aware of that and trust you, just talk about your concerns to him.

Comment: good experience by the sounds of it, you need to learn to work with all sorts of people in life. Probably come across a lot of drug users in the pharm industry.

Comment: I don't understand why you would quit just because of one (new) colleague. It sounds like you got too personal with her; try to keep things professional from now on and stick to work business.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for this site right now, and will likely be closed. Questions here require a clear goal, and should not just ask us to make a choice for you (as that is something only you can decide). Could you edit your question to indicate what your goal is? Do you want to stay at your job?

Comment: Also, maybe you could add some important details. You write "she’s been trying to get me fired " - could you explain what exactly she did? That is important for understanding the problem. And why does your boss want to "set up a meeting"? Is it because of what she did to "get me fired"? Please edit to clarify . Thanks!

Comment: Hey Emily, I edited my answer. Just one more thing: if you would request to be transferred to another location, what would that mean? Would that mean (for example) +30 minutes extra commute and working at night in a bad neighbourhood?

Comment: I would no longer be working overnights and I would have maybe another 5 minutes that I would have to take to get to work

Comment: Boss is setting up a meeting with just you? If so, wait until that to make a determination if you should quit or not.

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you shouldn't be the one considering moving, since you're not the one at fault here. As Kilisi said in a comment, you're gonna meet all kinds of people in your working life - some will grow to be your friends, others will just be straight up assholes. That's life!

Anyway, if you only have a few months left at this job, I'd just sit it out if I were you. Her tattling to your sister about what you said was a very nasty move. I'd advice you to keep it simple. Disengage from the druggy girl, restrict your conversations with her to simple niceties. Talk to your boss about your complaints. Your boss might not act on it right away, but at least he/she would know how you feel and how the new girl has acted. This could give you some cover if, at some point, something happens. Remember that you're probably not the only one who has noticed the new girls attitude and behavior. If she keeps acting like a total dick, your co-workers will back you up if a conflict arises.

> 'she’s been trying to get me fired since she started'

I think that it's probably obvious to everyone involved that she's spreading nonsense. While I can't judge your boss from my computer, I don't think you should be afraid of getting fired. I think it's more likely that your boss wants to talk about the rumors the new girl is spreading and ask what's up. Just honestly tell him/her about the new girls actions and that you'd rather be transferred than work with her.

If you do get transferred to another gas station for your remaining few months, where are you being transferred to? Just another comparable gas station with a comparable distance from your place of residence, or a tacky gas station in a bad neighborhood miles away?

Comment: It’s not a gut feeling. She’s been actively spreading lies among my coworkers that (thank goodness) do not believe her. She tried claiming I was trying to fight a customer (who even does that?), and that I’m lazy.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there are **some things that are not your concern at all**: if she's married and cheats **it's not your problem and it's not your place even to judge**, it's her private life and you are not part of it.
The only concerning thing about this could be the unprofessional behaviour, especially if flirting with the customers is frowned upon (how it is serious may depend on local culture and type of job).

I think you made also **a big mistake in trying to connect with her**: I can perfectly imagine you acted out of good faith and/or frustration, but one could also say that you "used" your sister's story, which is *very* private, to your personal advantage. Worse than that, she is depicted as having a quite unstable and dramatic personality, I've learned the hard way that oversharing with those people is only going to get you into trouble. So, she may have twisted your act in an exaggeration, but you have also a part of responsibility towards your sister.

If you are planning to leave this job not far distant in the future, I think it's worth just trying to ignore her or be transfered; or, if she is actively doing unprofessional things or sabotage you in any way, talk with your boss right away. It's unclear how she's "trying to get you fired", though: if there are serious issues, mention them in the meeting.

Comment: You're right, I should have known better. In the meeting I will definitely take up your advice

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just quit (two weeks notice for sure) or should I just
>   transfer?

Don't quit without having a job to go to.

Quitting because things are difficult is not always the best solution and could get to be a habit.

Besides, I would assume you are working because you need the money.

Seek a transfer. Or find a new job first, work out the notice period, then leave.

Comment: *＋1* for *"Don't quit without having a job to go to"*.